# Compare and copy files between two folders using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have One parent folder and a child folder. I have to compare the Parent and child folder and copy the missing files from Parent to Child folder. Only files should be copied, not directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rsync`.    It's designed for exactly this kind of job.  e.g. `rsync * Child/`

If, for some reason, you can only use shell built-ins, you could do something like this:

```
cd /path/to/Parent
for f in *; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -e "Child/$f" ] && cp "$f" Child/
done
```

In English:   using "$f" to loop over all files in the current directory, if "$f" is a regular file **AND** it does not exist in Child/, then copy it there.

Comment: Thanks @cas. I customised the rsync for my purpose and it worked. `rsync -r --exclude='*/' --update Test1/ Test1/Test2/`